# Putting MacBook Pro SSD into an external cradle

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, bootable-disk

My old MacBook Pro (2010) is now dead. It had a 500GB Samsung SSD inside (in replacement of the original HDD).

Some of the data where not in my time machine: I would like to extract the SSD and put it in an external USB cradle. As the SSD was the boot drive, do I need some special operation to read it when I'll attach it to my new computer, or is it enough to just put it in the external USB box?

--- EDIT ---
I put the SSD in an external USB3 cradle: the system mount it, but shows it empty! How can I retrieve my data?

Comment: What system do you mount it with? Should be another Mac. Windows might not be able to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything in particular. AFAIK, the fact that it was the boot drive should not affect it in any way. Just be careful to not boot accidentally from it when you startup your computer.

Comment: I've just put the SSD in a USB3 cradle. The system shows it empty!

Comment: Open Disk Utility and have a look at the SSD. Is your partition still there?